# javascript how to count the object and combin

Tags: javascript

I get the data from database like this:

```
var json = [   
    {
        name: "one",
        roles: [
            { role: "admin",state: 1 },
            { role: "operator",state: 1 },
            { role: "admin",state: 1 }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "two",
        roles: [
            { role: "admin2",state: 0 },
            { role: "operator",state: 1 },
            { role: "admin",state: 1 }
        ]
    }
];
```

And I want to become this

=>

```
 var json = [   
     {
         name: "one",
         roles:[...],
         data: [
             { "admin": 2,"eable": 2,"disable":0 },
             { "operator": 1,"eable": 1,"disable":0}
         ]
     },
     {
         name: "two",
         roles:[...],
         data: [
             { "admin": 1,"eable": 0,"disable":1 },
             { "admin2": 1,"eable": 1,"disable":0},
             { "operator": 1,"eable": 1,"disable":0}
         ]
     }
 ];
```

I'm getting stuck now, don't know what to do,please help.

Here is what I tried:

```
json.forEach(function(v,k){
    var ret = {
        "enable":0,
        "disable":0
    }
    json[k]['data'] = [];
    json[k]['roles'].forEach(function(v,k){
        json[k]['data'].push( v['role'] );
    })  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B9XkX/1/

Comment: You want to comment your JSON?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Sorry,I forget to remove the comment

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot to chew on because the data structure is weird but bear with me:

```
result = json.map(function(obj){
  // we can use map here to transform each object, whatever we return will
  // go into the result array.

  var roles = obj.roles.reduce(function(memo, item){

    // we need to turn a role object into a data object
    // but because we are counting the number of eable
    // and disable states we need to make a discreet object
    // that can hold the numbers without worrying about the
    // final data structure.

    memo[item.role] = memo[item.role] || {};
    memo[item.role].eable = memo[item.role].eable || 0;
    memo[item.role].disable = memo[item.role].disable || 0;

    // we initialize the memo object if we haven't seen the
    // role before.

    if (item.state === 1) {
      // we count eable for one state
      memo[item.role].eable += 1;
    } else if (item.state === 0) {
      // we count disable for the other state
      memo[item.role].disable += 1;
    }
    return memo;
  }, {});

  // now the roles object looks something like this:
  /**
   * {
   *   admin: {eable: 2, disable: 0},
   *   operator: {eable: 1, disable: 0}
   * }
   **/

  return {
    name: obj.name,
    roles: obj.roles,
    data: Object.keys(roles).map(function(key){
      // now we need to turn the roles object back into an array, so we use
      // Object.keys method to turn the keys on the roles object into an array
      // and we use map again to setup an object that we will use instead.
      var item = {};
      item[key] = 1; // {admin: 1}
      item.eable = roles[key].eable; // {admin:1, eable: 2}
      item.disable = roles[key].disable; // {admin:1, eable: 2, disable: 0}
      return item;
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Great! man. very good job, and thanks the very detail comments.